# NSTimeInterval memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nstimeinterval

I have a weird memory leak with NSTimeIntervall and NSDate. Here is my code:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 60*60*[[[Config alloc] getCacheLifetime] integerValue];
NSDate *maxCacheAge = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-interval];

if ([date compare:maxCacheAge] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
}
```

date is just an NSDate object, this should be fine. Instruments tells me that "interval" leaks, yet I do not quite understand this, how can I release a non-object? The function ends after the code snippet I posted here, so from my understanding interval should get automatically deallocated then.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably telling you that a leak is happening on that line.

The expression `[[[Config alloc] getCacheLifetime] integerValue]` is your problem.

First of all, you care creating an object (calling `alloc`) but you lose the reference to it before calling `release` or `autorelease`, so it is leaking.

Also, you really ought to call an `init` method immediately after allocating the object. Even if your `Config` class doesn't do anything special, `NSObject`'s `init` method will need to be called.

If you replace that line with

```
Config *config = [[Config alloc] init];
NSTimeInterval interval = 60*60*[[config getCacheLifetime] integerValue];
[config release];
```

That leak should be plugged up.

You are also leaking the `maxCacheAge` object. Inserting `[maxCacheAge autorelease];` before the if statement should fix that.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution! Now I also understand why the interval leaks. I applied you solution and it seems to work, is probably much better than my idea.

Comment: I would also like to point out that BOTH of these leaks are caught by the static analyzer (Xcode > Build > Build and Analyze) with no need to run Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, in case you come across the same issue, this is the solution:

```
[[ClubzoneConfig alloc] loadConfigFile];
NSTimeInterval interval = 60*60*[[[ClubzoneConfig alloc] getCacheLifetime] integerValue];
NSDate *maxCacheAge = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-interval];

if ([date compare:maxCacheAge] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    [maxCacheAge release];
    return YES;
} else {
    [maxCacheAge release];
    return NO;
}
```

The problem is that the maxCacheAge object needs to get released, as I own it (see link below).

I got it thanks to the awesome solution here: [iPhone Memory Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078016/iphone-memory-management)

Comment: Um, the way you're using `[ClubzoneConfig alloc]` looks wrong. See my answer for more.