# Correct way to release a UIColor PatternImage

Tags: iphone, uiimage, exc-bad-access, cgimage, uicolor

I have a few, full screen, `UIColor PatternImages` (in `scrollViews`) in my iPad app and am experiencing some memory problems (surprise?)
When I started having memory issues, I implemented lazy loading in my scrollviews.
When the problems continued, I moved away from factory methods 
(like `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:...]`)
to "alloc"ed methods 
(like `[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:...]`),
so I could respond to memory warnings by releasing pages.

However, whenever I release my UIColor PatternImages, I get an `“EXC_BAD_ACCESS”` error.

At first I thought this might be caused by my `[UIImage imageNamed:...]` pattern images, so I switched to `[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:...]` images, but this didn't help.  Just now I set `NSZombiesEnabled` and it tells me that the problem is:

```
-[UICGColor release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x187b50
```

With the backtrace:

```
#0  0x35823910 in ___forwarding___ ()
#1  0x35823860 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#2  0x357e53c8 in CFRelease ()
#3  0x357e48de in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop ()
#4  0x3116532c in NSPopAutoreleasePool ()
#5  0x341a7508 in _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler ()
#6  0x3580ac58 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#7  0x3580aacc in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#8  0x358020ca in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#9  0x35801c86 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#10 0x35801b8e in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#11 0x320c84aa in GSEventRunModal ()
#12 0x320c8556 in GSEventRun ()
#13 0x341dc328 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#14 0x341d9e92 in UIApplicationMain ()
#15 0x00002e5e in main (argc=1, argv=0x2fdff610) at...
```

I don't have any `UICGColor` objects either, so I'm thinking that somehow my "alloc"ed `UIColors` have underlying `UICGColor` autorelease objects...?  Any ideas/insight?

Comment: Regarding your last code section, of course you must not release the `CGImage` because you don't own own it (you didn't call `create`, `new` or `retain` on it). You should probably read the memory management guides (for Cocoa _and_ Core Foundation again).

Comment: Oh of course--careless.  I will remove that part of the question.  Thanks.  Any idea on the rest?  OK, reading guide now...

Comment: Having read some of the mm guides now (thanks @Ole), I believe that it _shouldn't_ matter if the patternImage is factory or alloced.  InitWithPatternImage should start by retaining the UIImage, and that is the retain that is released in UIColor dealloc.

Comment: I just shaved off another bit of the question "While I'm on topic, does it matter if the (UIImage) objects owned by the UIColor are factory or alloced?" which I just answered in the comment above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have worked something out, thanks in part to the (poorly tagged and titled) SO question/answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078016/iphone-memory-management).  What I needed to do was read-up about `UIView.backgroundColor`.  In my docs it says `@property(nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor`.  The "copy" here tells me that when I say something like:

```
myUIView.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:myUIImage];
```

The `myUIView.backgroundColor` is actually a different object to the `[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:myUIImage]`.  This separate `myUIView.backgroundColor` is, in fact, autoreleased, so when I go `[myUIView.backgroundColor release];` I am actually shooting myself in the foot.  What I need to do is:

```
UIColor* tmpColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:myUIImage];
currentPage.backgroundColor=tmpColor;
[tmpColor release];
```

(and of course, around that, I'm also allocing and releasing `myUIImage`).  Now to release my scrollView patternImage, I can just do something like `currentPage.backgroundColor=nil;` (like @BuildSucceeded) or `currentPage.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];` (not sure if there is a practical difference).  I guess internally, both of these cause `currentPage` to `autorelease` the old `backgroundColor`.  Since making these changes, I haven't been able to get my app to crash.

I need to say this:  I don't think C++ does it quite right, but C# and Java both manage quite nicely without any of this complicated release, autorelease, @property business.  Of course, if someone wanted to implement an analogous (to Objective-C) pointer management system in Java or C# they could, but of course no one wants this because it would be pretty useless. *Pleeeease* Apple, migrate away from Objective-C!

Answer (score 3):

Me too had the same problem and this is how i optimized my code.

After some analysis in Instruments and debugging i found out that colorwith pattern will occupy 1.12 mb with a responsible library called ripl_create. For each screen with colorWithPattern will occupy the same 1.12 and so you will have multiples oj 1.12 mb allocated. This sucked my app.so i decided No colorWithPattern.

I guess you want to set image to the background of a view. What i would suggest is keep a ImageView and place the image to it...

Now Coming to imageView optimization

If you want the image to be used in many part of the app or the view that contains the image will be frequently visited then go for imagenamed.

imageNamed will cache the image and will not release it even if you nil it or release it.

On the other case where you wwant image to be released

In you viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad assign the image to imageview

```
        NSString *fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourImage" ofType:@"png"];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation]];
```

inYour viewDidDisappear set nil to release the image

```
       imageView.image=nil;
```

Comment: Hi BuildSucceeded.  Couple of comments to make here.  First, yeah, I actually started with a whole lot of 1024x768 images.  I broke them up into _much_ smaller patternImages because I wanted to reduce the size of my binary.  That is when my memory problems started!  Looking at my original images, they range in size from about 100KB to 1MB, so 1.12MB _would_ be much worse.

Comment: Sorry man.. i said those details for iPhone.. For iPad i think it will take more memory size i think..iOS doesnt take memory according to the image size. For example if you have image for 320x480 imageView it will take 4 bytes for a pixel. so it will allocate 320x480x4 = 600kb for that imageView image..

Comment: I've read a lot recently about imageNamed.  IMHO, if I want to reuse an image, I can put the UIImage in my class @interface.  I don't yet quite understand how your code works, and get nervous when people say things like "set nil to release".  You are not effecting the retain count are you...?  I _understand_ the alloc/release rule.

Comment: So the iPad requires 1024x768x4=approx 3MB to display a full screen image?  So colorWithPattern might be better!?

Comment: So you want to reuse the image so now use imageName with no alloc.. dont worry about nil or release. What i intend to say is in my experience colorWithpattern takes up huge junk of memory so use imageViews where you want your image.

Comment: I think your answer is a bit off topic.  If I could just release my UIColors correctly I think everything would be OK.  Anybody?

Comment: I think Instruments is your best friend here.. use that and find which takes more memory... For me in iPhone colorWithpattern takes 1.12 MB and imageView takes 600kb

Comment: Mmmm...  I _am_ using ImageViews--its just their bgs are patterned.  You mean use UIImages, rather than PatternImages.  Mmm... back to where I was 1 mth of development ago! :-(

Comment: I'm OK if PatternImages require more memory--because I get a _much_ smaller binary to compensate.  I - just - need - to - release - the UIColors - properly!

Comment: Oh, perhaps you mean tiling a whole lot of UIImageViews, each with the same (pattern) image!?  It would be so crazy if that turned out to be better than using UIColor patternImages!  Is that what you mean?